# Sequence of complex numbers with minimum distance between elements

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

**CONTEXT**

This is part of an exercise that introduces Weierstrass zeta and pe functions. It is Exercise VIII.3.2 in Conway's "Functions of One Complex Variable I".

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be an arbitrary sequence of complex numbers such that $|a_n| \to \infty$. Suppose that there is a $r>0$ such that $|a_n - a_m| \geq r$ for all $n \neq m$. Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{|a_n|^3} < \infty.$$

**MY SOLUTION**

Suppose, WLOG, that $r=2$. Let
$${k_n} = \min\{k \in \mathbb Z^+: \forall m \geq k,\ |a_m| > n\}.$$
Create now a grid using the Gaussian integers. Since $|a_n-a_m| \geq 2$, for all $n\neq m$, every side one square will contain at most one element of the sequence that precedes $a_{n_k}$. Hence we can upperbound the sum of the series as follows.
$$\mathcal S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{|a_n|^3} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{A(n)}{|a_{k_n}|^3},$$
where $A(n)$ is the number of side one squares that partially lie in the annulus $n-1\leq |z|\leq n$. If a square partially lies in the annulus, then it is entirely contained in the circle of radius $n+2$. Similarly, if a square lies inside the circle of radius $n-3$, then none of it lies in the annulus. Therefore
$$A(n) \leq \pi(n+2)^2 - \pi(n-3)^2 \leq 10\pi n.$$
Using the fact that $|a_{n_k}| > n$ we can upperbound $\mathcal S$ as
$$\mathcal S \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{10\pi n}{n^3} = \frac{5\pi^3}3.$$

**QUESTION**

Is my reasoning correct? Are there any flaws in the proof?

Comment: Looks good to me. Also, it appears that the series converges with exponent $2+ \epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minor flaw in your proof. The uniform upper bound $\frac{5\pi^3}3$  does not work for the **whole** series $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{|a_n|^3} $ if one of the complex numbers $a_n$ has a suitable small positive modulus (we are also assuming that $a_n\not=0$ for  all $n\geq 1$).

Moreover, in your proof, for simplicity's sake we may use square annuli instead of circular annuli.

Let $r=2$ (or $r>\sqrt{2}$, anyway the value of $r>0$ has no effect on the convergence). It follows that each unit square in the grid $\mathbb{Z}^2$ may contain at most one complex number $a_n$. For any integer $k\geq 1$, let $Q_k=[-k,k]\times [-k,k]$ then
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{|a_n|^3}&=\sum_{a_n\in Q_1}\frac1{|a_n|^3}+
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{a_n\in Q_{k+1}\setminus Q_{k}}\frac1{|a_n|^3}\\
&\leq \frac{4}{d^3}+
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{|Q_{k+1}\setminus Q_{k}|}{k^3}
< \frac{4}{d^3}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{12k}{k^3}<\frac{4}{d^3}+2\pi^2
\end{align}$$
where $d=\min_{n\geq 1} |a_n|>0$ (such positive minimum exists) and $$|Q_{k+1}\setminus Q_{k}|=4((k+1)^2-k^2)=8k+4\leq 12k$$
denotes the area of the square annulus $Q_k\setminus Q_{k-1}$. Notice that the modulus of any complex number  in $Q_{k+1}\setminus Q_{k}$ is $\geq k$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: You are welcome!